# Using a .svg file in HTML from a URL?

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to use an svg from an external source in my html. Let's say I have this svg:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg

I found many ways to do this, including:

```
<img src="your.svg"/> 
<object data="your.svg"/> 
<iframe src="your.svg"/> 
<embed src="your.svg"/> 
<div style="background:url(your.svg)">...</div>
```

But unfortunately, the styling I have to use applies to svg tags. If I use this for example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">       
<image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg"/>    
</svg>
```

It won't show up on my page, I just get an empty white square! Is there anyway I can do this inside svg tags? Thanks!

Comment: Why do your styles only apply to svg tags?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working in a multi team environment. I have to use the provided styling, or I will have to contact those responsible and ask them to change it, and that could take a long time.

Comment: actual production environment where specific styles are applied to html elements directly? interesting. you can take a look at my answer. maybe it helps.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to specify a width and height for your svg to display properly:

```
<svg width="90" height="90">       
     <image xlink:href="your.svg" src="yourfallback.png" width="90" height="90"/>    
</svg>
```

**Update**

You can do this via CSS too of course, but you have to be sure that your `<image>` tag has width and height set in your CSS if you don't specify the html attributes directly:

```
 svg {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
 }

 image {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
 }
```

This will set the size of your actual image (the svg) to `100px * 100px`, but has a "wrapper" of `150px`. Regarding to your comment to your original question, maybe that's why you don't see your image, because you dont have set a width / height and only styles which apply to your wrapping element (`<svg>`)

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7334vrmq/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kryptik, thanks for your response. But wouldn't that just defeat the whole point of the provided styling if I am specifying them directly?

Comment: The provided styling is like this: svg {
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
  }

Comment: well but this won't affect the `<image/>` at all, just the `svg` element which serves as your wrapper. you still have to specify a width for the `<image>`.

Comment: This way you can't set fill of the SVG anymore...