# How to Convert svg link into svg tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an link which has the svg file with the format of svg .
[svgfilelink](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/AJ_Digital_Camera.svg)

And this link has the following content :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1">
<title>Rectangle Copy 14</title>
<defs>
    <linearGradient x1="5.7671933%" y1="50.1613046%" x2="99.3732272%" y2="50.1613046%" id="linearGradient-1">
        <stop stop-color="#59D08F" offset="0%"/>
        <stop stop-color="#26C2DC" offset="100%"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="06-Shapes-Properties" transform="translate(-1166.000000, -354.000000)" stroke="url(#linearGradient-1)" stroke-width="2">
        <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" x="1167" y="355" width="18" height="18"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

As of now I'm adding this link as src in **img** tag .
But I need this link as svg format.
I have tried few methods. But didn't help.
Is there any possible ways to convert the url into **svg** tag in JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: Tried this ? `<img src="test.svg" />` ?

Comment: @Raptor . That is what I'm currently using. 
But I can't be able to change the fill color and other attributes of svg via image tag. 
So I'm actually looking for getting the svg value and append it as innerhtml inside a div tag

Comment: I think you mean _URL_, not "link". If you want to get the SVG source code from that URL - then you will need to make an HTTP request (AJAX/fetch/...) to get it.

Comment: @farooq look at this new method introduced recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70986923/188331

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097191/using-a-svg-file-in-html-from-a-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to do but you can directly fetch that svg and render it to the DOM using `innerHTML` or something like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with react

```js
let svgUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahuldkjain/github-profile-readme-generator/master/src/images/icons/Social/hackerrank.svg'
  
function getTheSvg(url) {
   return fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
}
        
getTheSvg(svgUrl).then(res => {
   let svgDiv = document.querySelector('.svg')
   svgDiv.innerHTML = res
})
```

```css
svg {
   height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class='svg'><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used `create-react-app`, it already uses `@svgr/webpack` package, so you can do this, which will cause the image to load inline as React components containing the SVG elements directly, instead of by a link:

```
import { ReactComponent as RectangleIcon } from './rectangle.svg';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return <RectangleIcon />
}
```

If you are not using create-react-app so not using svgr yet, you can add it to your project ([see docs](https://react-svgr.com/docs/getting-started/))

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replaceSVGWithSVGFromURL(className, svgURL) {
  var targetElement = document.querySelector("." + className);
  if (targetElement) {
    fetch(svgURL)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(svgContent => {
        console.log(svgContent);
        var svgElement = targetElement.querySelector("svg");
        if (svgElement) {
          var newSVGElem = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgContent, "image/svg+xml")
            .documentElement;
          targetElement.replaceChild(newSVGElem, svgElement);
        }
      });
  }
}

replaceSVGWithSVGFromURL(
  "logo-preview",
  "https://heatmap-project-2022.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hugart.svg"
);
```

```js
let svgUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahuldkjain/github-profile-readme-generator/master/src/images/icons/Social/hackerrank.svg'
  
function getTheSvg(url) {
   return fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
}
        
getTheSvg(svgUrl).then(res => {
   let svgDiv = document.querySelector('.svg')
   svgDiv.innerHTML = res
})
```

```css
svg {
   height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class='svg'><div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).