# SVG change dynamic color

Tags: css, reactjs, css-filters

I have svg images in menu list but want to change color of svg image(.svg). It is only possible using filter css property. I got the filter value from hex to css filter (library : hex-to-css-filter). it is giving correct value for color but react can not set filter property on that images.
I tried using inline and also using root variable in css. Some code snippets describe below:

```
const filterValue = hexToCSSFilter('#575a98').filter;     // invert(40%) sepia(15%) saturate(1783%) hue-rotate(199deg) brightness(83%) contrast(84%)
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--menu-image-filter', `${filterValue}`);
```

Also in style.css

```
:root {
  --menu-image-filter: invert(79%) sepia(28%) saturate(1346%) hue-rotate(77deg) brightness(90%) contrast(85%); // Default
}


span.svg_path img{
    width: 35px;
    filter: var(--menu-image-filter);;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried fill and stroke method in css ?

Comment: I tried but i don't have svg tag. I have .svg image and it is not working on it.

Comment: You can change svg's color using `fill` property as well.

Comment: @farooq I have image url => http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/avatar/20220425112102_506.svg

Comment: @VinodPatidar It won't work if you add svg as src . 
Please add it as a HTML tag and try fill

Comment: @farooq But i don't have any options because path is comming from backend.

Comment: @VinodPatidar convert the given url into svg tag and then you can use the svg tag to change color. Checkout my last question for the clear answer.

Comment: @farooq How we can convert ?

Comment: @VinodPatidar https://stackoverflow.com/a/71995745/8240120

Comment: @farooq Will try that way and reach out to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the given svg url into text and then you can change the color by using the fill and stroke methods in CSS.

the code would be,

```
    function getTheSvg(url) {
        return fetch(url).then((res) => res.text());
    }
       const getTextFromSvg = async (url) => {

       let svgVal = await getTheSvg(url).then((res) => {

      return res;
    });
getTextFromSvg("https://yoururl.svg");
```

Comment: Now i'm getting cors error only for fetching these svg files. All requests are working perfectly but these requests are giving cors error. So i can't get the svg text from featch api.

Comment: @VinodPatidar Then you should ask the back-end team to remove cors policy .